# issue displaying multiple images wx.python

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, wxpython, wxwidgets

Okay so I'm seriously lost here and any guidance would be appreciated. I have a program that displays all the wafer maps within a given time range.[image shown below] when I input the the dates 9/1/18- 9/15/18 it outputs fine . When I do 9/15/18-9/30/18  it also works fine but when I query the whole month I get an error. I'm starting to think this might be a memory related issues but I'm not too  knowledgeable about memory. I do know that python handles memory by itself. Also I do have 16GB of RAM and working on a 64bit architecture. The setup is a GUI that allows you to pick a file and pick 2 dates then another wx.frame appears displaying the wafer maps.

the error that I receive when I query a larger date is the following

```
image = bitmap.ConvertToImage()
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "hbmp" failed at ..\..\src\msw\dib.cpp(139) in wxDIB::Create(): wxDIB::Create(): invalid bitmap
```

here's the parent function where that is being called from

```
def SetBitmapLabel(self, bitmap, createOthers=True):
    """
    Set the bitmap to display normally.
    This is the only one that is required.

    If `createOthers` is ``True``, then the other bitmaps will be generated
    on the fly.  Currently, only the disabled bitmap is generated.

    :param wx.Bitmap `bitmap`: the bitmap for the normal button appearance.

    .. note:: This is the bitmap used for the unselected state, and for all other
       states if no other bitmaps are provided.
    """

    self.bmpLabel = bitmap
    if bitmap is not None and createOthers:
        image = bitmap.ConvertToImage()
        imageutils.grayOut(image)
        self.SetBitmapDisabled(wx.Bitmap(image))
```

and here's where that function above is called

```
def SetBitmap(self, bmp):
    """
    Sets the bitmap representation of the current selected colour to the button.

    :param wx.Bitmap `bmp`: the new bitmap.
    """

    self.SetBitmapLabel(bmp)
    self.Refresh()
```

any help would be greatly appreciated because at this point I have no idea where to go from here. Maybe the GUI im working w/ is only operating at 32bit ? not sure. Not sure if the image is needed but here is below
 [image: wafer maps]

**EDIT**
thanks to the guys below I discovered that the reason this is happening is because my GDI objects reach 10,000 for the script which is the limitations set by windows. Now I have to find a work around for this. Will probably post another question to dive into this

Comment: Double check the wxwidgets component lables' names and also the image path.

Comment: any reason why it works w/ a shorter query but fails at a bigger one ? as far as the label names and the image path are concerned ?

Comment: It definitely looks like you're running out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could be running out of GDI resources, i.e. creating the actual bitmap object (`HBITMAP`) fails. Unfortunately there is not too much that can be done in this case other than obvious: create fewer (and/or smaller) bitmaps.

Also check that you don't leak any bitmaps, i.e. if the problem only starts appearing after you run your application for some time, this could well be the case. Many diagnostic tools under Windows (e.g. [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)) can show you GDI resources consumed by your process, check if they don't grow while the program is running.

Comment: Hey , you we're absolutely right . the Script reached the 10k limit allowed for one process thanks for showing me this , I would had never known

Answer (score 1):

As VZ said, it seems that you are running out of GDI resources (i.e. bitmap), which has nothing to do with available RAM, but with OS.

If this is the case, I'd go this route:

- Store your images in wxImage's objects. They will use RAM, but not GDI resources.
- Handle each window paint event. In this handler, convert the `wxImage` to a `bitmap` and blit it to the window. The bitmap can be released now.

Comment: @JeffPernia Better open a new question with the new code, and the problems you meet.

Comment: could you explain the 2nd bullet point in simple terms ? it's kind of confusing for me

Comment: @JeffPernia You `Bind()` the wx:EVT_PAINT type event to some function [See Events wxPython doc](https://docs.wxpython.org/events_overview.html). In this function you get the proper `wxImage` and show it in the window.

Answer (score -1):

Encounter the same problem. Simple solution solves the problem:

```
import subprocess, time

while True:
    cd = "py img_get_xp.py"
    subprocess.Popen(cd)
    time.sleep(600)
    subprocess.Popen('tasklist>task.txt', shell=True).communicate()
    tasks = open('task.txt')
    lines = tasks.read()[::-1]
    pos = lines.find("exe.nohtyp")
    pid = lines[pos - 22:pos - 18][::-1]
    subprocess.call(['taskkill', '/F', '/T', '/PID', pid])
```